# iOS 7 crash due to EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV). Can anybody help me to understand the crash report?

Tags: ios, ios7, memory-leaks, crash-reports

I am getting weird crash in my application running in iOS 7 but in iOS 6 app is working fine. I am performing some operations. After 5-6 operations are completed I am experiencing this crash. This number can go till 20 also or 1 also. Attaching crash log with this.

```
Incident Identifier: 6702CA20-9832-4305-B723-588C6B33C199
CrashReporter Key:   0370a1a51d424d34102c66389c6b00b12585aa57
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:            mobile [2958]
Path:                
Identifier:          
Version:             2.0.0.401
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-02 13:35:50.243 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xef264ee9
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3af9eb22 objc_msgSend + 2
1   UIFoundation                    0x38384d5e -[NSParagraphStyle _deallocExtraData] + 54
2   UIFoundation                    0x383858ca -[NSParagraphStyle dealloc] + 22
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3073d650 CFRelease + 552
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30749a1e -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc] + 130
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3afaeb06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
6   UIKit                           0x3304be68 -[UILabel dealloc] + 116
7   UIKit                           0x32f80402 -[UIView dealloc] + 362
8   UIKit                           0x3305223a -[UIScrollView dealloc] + 830
9   UIKit                           0x33051cb4 -[UIScrollView removeFromSuperview] + 60
10  UIKit                           0x32f80402 -[UIView dealloc] + 362
11  UIKit                           0x33199088 -[_UIModalItemContentView dealloc] + 116
12  UIKit                           0x3323d432 -[_UIModalItemAlertContentView dealloc] + 70
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3afa0002 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3074097c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
15  CoreFoundation                  0x307d80dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                  0x307d7cf2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
17  CoreFoundation                  0x307d608e __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
18  CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
19  CoreFoundation                  0x30740a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
20  GraphicsServices                0x3543427e GSEventRunModal + 134
21  UIKit                           0x32fe4044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
22  mobile                  0x0005d2c2 main (main.m:15)
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x3b4abab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f83c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b490210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3b48ff96 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307d77be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307d5ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30740a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x3894e266 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307d77be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307d5ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30740a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2f7c3584 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2f7b799c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562440 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x307db680 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  GCDAsyncSocket-CFStream
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307d77be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307d5ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30740a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x3112e3d6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x3117f30c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   mobile                  0x000f6228 +[GCDAsyncSocket cfstreamThread] (GCDAsyncSocket.m:6741)
9   Foundation                      0x311f0c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307d77be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307d5ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30740a06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x3117b2f2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x311f0c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54fa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b54f888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x307d77be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x307d5ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30740c22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30784736 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x30df7230 ___lldb_unnamed_function1404$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562440 __select + 20
1   ExternalAccessory               0x31119352 -[EAInputStream _readInputFromAccThread] + 342
2   Foundation                      0x311f0c82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cac1a _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5cab8a _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3b562c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3b5c8c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0xef264ee9    r1: 0x33566b29      r2: 0x3cf673f0      r3: 0x00000001
    r4: 0x160815a0    r5: 0x33566b29      r6: 0x0000002c      r7: 0x27dc88ac
    r8: 0x160815a4    r9: 0x158af438     r10: 0x14e8846c     r11: 0x14e88430
    ip: 0x3cf59864    sp: 0x27dc88a0      lr: 0x38384d63      pc: 0x3af9eb22
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: Aren't you getting this at a particular line? If so, adding that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You should add the line as Edit and format it :|

Comment: while (!nak && !ack && !ack2 && !timeoutReached && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]]);



Wherever may be crash exception break point is coming to the above line.

Comment: First, do you have the DWARF symbol folder .dSYM?

Comment: @Eddie: I am not aware of that but found that at:    

Right Click on your archive -> Show in Finder -> Right click on file and click on Show package contents.Here you will find your .dSYM file.

Comment: @Inder Well, that's one location, if it's for the correct build. However, you're still still dealing with objc_msgSend which often times obfuscates what actually caused the problem. Here's an article that might help: http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html

Answer (score 1):

Your app crashes while a UILabel inside a UIScrollView inside an alert is deallocated. I'd suspect that either your app overwrites memory somewhere and this is just a symptom, or you are using some alert in a non-standard way, possibly changing a paragraph style somewhere in the alert in a way that's wrong.

First step would be to turn all reasonable warnings on in the compiler, use the static analyser to find problems, and fix all of them.